# lsof "lies" when using options?

Tags: linux, lsof

I have a problem where my Java application opens too many files. Debugging this issue, I am dependent on using lsof. 
However running lsof this way takes too much time (more than one minutt):

```
lsof |grep "java"
```

I should be able to run it using the -p option, however it "lies". It shows too few lines.

```
lsof -p <PID of the java process>
```

This is my proof :

```
lsof |grep java  | wc -l 
1510146

lsof -p 802 | wc -l
4735
```

The same happens if I use the -u option limiting to username (process owner).

My system is : 
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Am I missing something ?  Is there an alternative to using lsof ?

Answer (score 1):

lsof is not lying.
The output of the command:

```
lsof |grep java  | wc -l
```

may contain results of files or processes opened by other programs.

The result you are searching for is the result of the command:

```
lsof -p <PID> | wc -l
```

You can increase the limit of opened files for the user running your java application adding this line in  /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
<USER>   hard   nofile  65536
```

you can check the current user's limits by typing:

```
su - <USER>
ulimit -a
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. However I do not think that is why.

My java process has pid 41866

`lsof |grep "^java      41866" |wc -l 
 > 857349
`

while :

`lsof -p 41866 |wc -l
> 1634`

See the HUGE difference ? 
So when I run 'lsof' with no options, it displays many many more lines which start with java and its pid, than when I run 'lsof -p <PID>'

I really think this must be a bug.

Comment: lsof |grep "^java 41866" |wc -l > 857349 show you also the threads of a process. One process may have more than one thread. [link] http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/linux-process-and-threads

Answer (score 0):

`lsof` without parameter lists all open files, including files which are not using file descriptors – such as current working directories, memory mapped library files, and executable text files.

`lsof -p <PID>` lists open file descriptors. A file descriptor is a data structure used by a program to get a handle on a file, the most well know being 0,1,2 for standard in, standard out, and standard error.

See: https://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observation, it seems that

```
lsof | grep <pid> | wc -l
```

will give duplicate count, because every thread in the specified process will add a line, e.g. if your process have 8 threads, the result will be more than 8x the actual file count.

On the other hand,

```
lsof -p <PID> | wc -l
```

produce more exact result, because each file is counted (printed) only once.

Although I have not found official reference for this issue yet.